# Redesigning product blocks in search results / listings

Tags: usability, lists, e-commerce, search-results

What are some good practices when it comes to presenting a product on a listing / search result page when they contain a lot of information? Currently the product block for our website looks like this:

[image: Product block]

As you can see, there's a lot information to display, and unfortunately as much as I would love to start blank I can't. Surprisingly enough, our users tend to look up all the product information whilst still on listing / search and not on the product page itself.

I welcome any suggestions on how to change the product block that would provide better usability and not have a negative impact on the customer experience.

Comment: What evidence is there that this information isn't right? Is too much? Have you canvassed your users for their opinions? Have they said that some information is missing or that the information is an overload?

Comment: Most of them complained about information overload. They don't use Compare functionality at all, instead put a lot of effort into reading one product attributes, then moving back and forth between products. They complain that pictures are too small (magnifying glass appears on hover). They get really confused about product availibility. I could go on, but those 3 were mentioned by most.

Comment: You note that your users "tend to look up all the product information while still on listing and not on the product page" but I wonder if that's purely because the current design forces so much information into the listing rather than because that's what users want?

Comment: I wonder whether it is a case that the compare is too small and lost in the product information in the bottom left? Is there the opportunity to create 4-5 re-designs of this page and get feedback on it? That would be worth 10x more than what we could suggest here.

Comment: By feedback for redesign, do you mean doing the redesigns and pasting them here or within the company? Currently I'm browsing through similar websites looking for benchmarks that could have something eye-opening for me. And yes, compare is way too small and not does not have any interaction effect, users ignore it.

Comment: May I ask... Why is all of that information needed on the product block? Usually speaking, in e-commerce the block is left for the most pertinent information (such as product title, the price, and a brief description). Upon clicking they will be taken to the product detail page where all the information is laid out. On that page you will get CTAs. Why not reduce cognitive load when on the SERP page? What's the context of this site?

Comment: Matt, have you got one real product you could post in this format, from your website? It'd be good to see what data the fields show.

Comment: are the users aware about the presence of a detail page? Or are they just assuming this is the detail page and therefore expect to see everything here? I won't be surprised if the concept of listing vs detail page is not top of mind for users.

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility that your compare function is too small and tucked away so that the user's eye, now tired from scanning all that info, simply misses it completely. Perhaps moving it to the focus region around the price/cta buttons might encourage more interaction that way?

Answer (score 0):

It's possibility to add UI controlers, which changing the view of displaying product:
[image]

In the case of single product page - it's not a clear and universal solution.
It depends on a lot of variables (like industry, customer type, amount of information needed)

**Suggestions and ideas:**

- highlight and raise a section with warehouse information / availability
- limit the number of attributes (or present them in the form of icons with a tooltip)
- change the location of the coupon and present the benefit in a clearer form
- distinguish main cta as primary button and the second as secondary
- integrate the comparison action with the actions on the right (so
  that they are all close together)(?)
- Promotion 1 and promotion 2 are unclear and in non-standard places

---

Naturalistically, the next step will be refining the UI (spaces, fonts, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could go with assumption it is quicker for users to check information right away, as it is simpler to compare products when they are next to each other.

If you have strong established practice and know your users are satisfied with existing state, you don't need to do much.

What you could to i.e.:

- In a questionare / interviews / with analytics, find out which information are most valuable for users from the ones you have in product item box..
- Leave that information in basic version of the box, and have option to "extend" each box
- Maybe also have configuration setting to have cards extended or basic by default

This would probably then be something thats in UX called "Progressive Disclosure".

Reading suggestion for this topic: https://www.justinmind.com/blog/progressive-disclosure/

Especially part under: "Progressive disclosure done right: the guidelines"